# AdGuard blocks side navigation container

Tags: css, adblock, sidenav

I'm working on website. I used code from this page https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav for my sidenav container. It works for me but only offline or with my AdGuard turned off.

Is there any way to display it on server on webpage with AdGuard on run.

Comment: Make sure you don't use classes or id's that may be mistaken for Ad containers.  Basically like id="adspace" or class="ad"

Comment: These are names of my class n id <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">.
Do You think that they might be troublemakers?